# Как преобразовать binary(111010000001110000000000) в integer?

Tags: java

Как преобразовать binary(записано в string 111010000001110000000000) в integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parseInt(String s, int radix)
int foo = Integer.parseInt("111010000001110000000000", 2);

valueOf(String s, int radix)
Integer foo = Integer.valueOf("111010000001110000000000", 2);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html